# Add multiple dialogs into a single page

Tags: primeng

I'm working into an Angular app that displays some data into a dataGrid as follows.

```
<p-dataGrid [value]="docs" [paginator]="true" [rows]="8">
  <ng-template let-doc pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
      <span>{{doc.title}}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataGrid>
```

I'm trying to add a button, that when clicked, displays some info regarding the selected doc. I did it as follows:

```
<p-dataGrid [value]="docs" [paginator]="true" [rows]="8">
  <ng-template let-doc pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
      <span>{{doc.title}}</span>
      <button (click)="showDialog(doc.id)" pButton type="button" icon="fas fa-info-circle" iconPos="left" label="Details"></button>
      <p-dialog id="{{doc.id}}" #{{doc.id}} [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="300" [responsive]="true">
        <p>{{doc.title}}</p>
      </p-dialog>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataGrid>
```

Into my component, I added a function:

```
display: boolean = false;
showDialog(id: string) {
  alert(id);
  this.display = true;
}
```

The problem is since I'm using the same variable ("display") to control the visibility of all dialogs, browser gets lost about which dialog it should show/hide. In general, it uses the last one.

Since the quantity of elements into the screen is variable, I cannot create display1, display2, displayN variables. So my doubt is, how do I dynamically control the visibility of an element?

I tried something like with no luck:

```
showDialog(id: string) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  e.attributes['ng-reflect-visible'].value = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create as many `p-dialog` elements as docs. Only once should be enough. So if you extract yours `p-dialog` outside of your `p-datagrid`, HTML code becomes something like that :

```
<p-dataGrid [value]="docs" [paginator]="true" [rows]="8">
  <ng-template let-doc pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
      <span>{{doc.title}}</span>
      <button (click)="showDialog(doc.id)" pButton type="button" icon="fas fa-info-circle" iconPos="left" label="Details"></button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataGrid>

<p-dialog id="dialog" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="300" [responsive]="true">
        <h1>{{selectedDoc.title}}</h1>
        Details : {{selectedDoc.details}}
</p-dialog>
```

where `selectedDoc` is assigned when you click on a button :

```
showDialog(id: string) {
    this.selectedDoc = this.docs[id-1];
    this.display = true;
}
```

Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kpcLedtvWG6xIjFLZpXZ?p=preview)